# kops validate cluster: returns "cluster not found" even though cluster is healthy and kubectl works fine

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I created a cluster using kops.  It worked fine and the cluster is healthy.  I can see my nodes using kubectl and have created some deployments and services.  I tried adding a node using "kops edit ig nodes" and got an error "cluster  not found".  Now I get that error for all kops commands:

```
kops validate cluster
Using cluster from kubectl context: <clustername>

cluster "<clustername>" not found
```

So my question is: where does kops look for clusters and how do I configure it to see my cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My KOPS_STATE_STORE environment variable got messed up.  I corrected it to be the correct s3 bucket and everything is fine.

```
export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://correctbucketname
```

Comment: This answer hints at a critical distinction between kops and kubectl. Kubectl is executing against the cluster itself, but kops is looking at both the cluster and the state store in S3. So if kubectl works but kops doesn't, the state store is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kubectl and Kops access the configuration file from the following the location.

When the cluster is created.The configuration will be saved into a users

```
$HOME/.kube/config
```

I have attached the link for further insight for instance, If you have another config file you can EXPORT it.  [kube-config](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_export_kubecfg.md)

Comment: I think that's all configured correctly because it knows what the cluster is.  I'm just not sure where the "cluster not found" is coming from.  Is it trying to hit the api server or does kops have an internal registry that I need to refresh/update?

Comment: As I understand, Kops get the location of the API-Server from the above file. then it try to make the connection with found location. So If Kops does not find the right cluster. you need to validate `.kube/config` file.

Comment: kops export is not working either "kops export kubecfg <clustername>" also returns cluster "<clustername>" not found.

Comment: And doesn't kubectl get it's configuration from the same place?  kubectl is working fine:  kubectl get nodes
NAME                            STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ip-172-20-36-100.ec2.internal   Ready     master    20h       v1.8.6
ip-172-20-40-88.ec2.internal    Ready     node      20h       v1.8.6
ip-172-20-61-95.ec2.internal    Ready     node      20h       v1.8.6

Comment: If you can run the following command `kubectl cluster-info -v 8` you will find raw logs. you can verify if it's accessing the right file

Comment: Try following command for listing the clusters `kops get clusters`

Comment: Yes, kubectl is working fine.  That command shows my cluster and all its services.  Config is coming from the correct file.  I just don't know why kops can't find my cluster anymore.

Comment: kops get clusters: "no clusters found"

Comment: we can try to export it again `kops export kubecfg=$HOME/.kube/config`